# Exercise from analysis book about limit of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that $a_n$ is an infinite sequence and there exist $t$ and $k$ such that $0< k < 1$ and
$$  |a_n − t| \leq k|a_{n-1}-t|  $$
for $n = 2, 3, \dots$. Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = t$.

First it seemed to me easy one. but I couldn't handle with it. we have studied monotonic sequences, the rule preservation of inequalities on limit. Can anyone suggest any proof or hint.

Comment: Please use Latex, this is unreadable.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Those are very difference questions.

Comment: This has appeared a million times on this site.

Comment: but how search latex formulas actually I had searched before posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $b_n = |a_n - t|$. If $b_N = 0$ then $b_n = 0$ for $n \geq N$ so $b_n \to 0$. Suppose $b_n \ne 0$.Then $b_n \leq k b_{n-1} < b_{n-1}$ so $b_n$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below by $0$. Thus it converges. Suppose $b_n \to b$. Suppose $b \ne 0$. Then $b_n > b$ for all $n$, but $k^{-1}(b-kb) >0$ so there is some $n$ s.t. $b_n < b + k^{-1}(b-kb)$ so $b_{n+1} < k b_n < kb + b - kb = b$, contradicting $b_n > b$. Thus $b =0 $.

So $b_n \to 0$, hence $a_n \to t$.

Answer (score 1):

Show that

1. $k^n \to 0$
2. $|a_n-t| \leq k^{n-1} |a_1-t|$

and then use the squeeze theorem on $0 \leq |a_n-t| \leq k^{n-1} |a_1-t|$.